# Set session query timeout

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, oracle-xe

When I develop complex queries and I make a mistake (e.g. a wrong join that will make the query run for hours or days) Oracle becomes unusable (you can't even start a local SYS session from SQL*Plus). I have to log into the Windows Server box that hosts it and restart the Oracle services.

In this situations I'd prefer to get the query killed if it runs for more than a certain (short) amount of time.

I've read about profiles and `LIMIT_USER_QUERY_TIME` but it isn't flexible enough: you have to choose a fixed timeout and enforce it on every action of the given user.

Is it possible to establish a variable timeout on specific connections or queries? Something like:

```
-- Fake directive:
ALTER SESSION SET abort_queries_that_run_for_more_than_x_seconds 60;

SELECT *
FROM FOO
CROSS JOIN BAR;

ALTER SESSION SET abort_queries_that_run_for_more_than_x_seconds NULL;
```

Comment: You can't cancel the query in your client? Why not just kill the session?

Comment: @Colin'tHart I can kill the entire client app (it's a PHP script running on Apache, BTW) but Oracle will keep on running the query anyway. How can I kill the session? I cannot log into Oracle...

Comment: use Oracle ODBC Driver to enable Query Timeout

Comment: @AhmadAbuhasna There was a project where I had to connect to Oracle via ODBC. It was so painful I'm not willing to repeat. Furthermore, I'm not convinced that Oracle server will actually decide to stop the query.

Comment: If you can create your own OCI calls, then you can do it, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/756157/391445